# Element Not Visible after Switching to NewWindow

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing, nightwatch.js

After switching to new window, only 'urlContains' is working.

Nothing else is happening(neither click nor elementVisible or anything)

Partial code of nightwatch:

```
'Order Module' : function(browser) {
browser
    .useXpath()
    .waitForElementVisible("@OrderTab", 20000)
    .pause(5000)
    .click("@OrderTab")
    .pause(5000)
    .useCss()
    .waitForElementVisible("input[title = 'New']", 20000)
    .click("input[title = 'New']")
    .useXpath()
    .waitForElementVisible("@OrderTextBox']", 20000)
    .verify.urlContains('https://invoiceit-s.na30.visual.force.com/apex/createJobStep1?retURL=%2Fa0K%2Fo&save_new=1&sfdc.override=1')
    .setValue("@OrderTextBox", "Order Name")
    .pause(10000)
    .click("@LinkIconForNewWindow")
    .pause(10000)
    .window_handles(function(result) {
        this.verify.equal(result.value.length, 2, '2 windows should be open')
        var handle = result.value[1]
        this.switchWindow(handle)
        this.verify.urlContains('https://invoiceit-s.na30.visual.force.com/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lkfm=j_id0%3AjobForm&lknm=j_id0%3AjobForm%3Apb%3Arender%3Aj_id38%3A0%3Aj_id39&lktp=001&lksrch=')
        this.useXpath()
        this.waitForElementVisible("@searchBox", 20000)
    })
    .pause(20000)
    .end() }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not familiar with Xpath,Can you post the screen-print of the element block? May be i can help you

PS:Dont use too much pause(), it will slow down your test program,nightwatch will check element every 500ms.

Edit 1 :The problem may be because of '`@searchBox`' element,is this in the first tab of your browser after you clicked Pop-up Button ? If yes, it should be like:

```
.window_handles(function(result) {
      var home = result.value[0], // your first tab
          handle = result.value[1]; // second tab
         this
            .switchWindow(handle)
            .verify.urlContains('https://invoiceit') 
            .useXpath() 
            .switchWindow(home) // you need to switch back to first tab , even you close the pop-up.
            .waitForElementVisible("@searchBox", 20000) 
    })
```

PS:my answer from this post may help.[Loop is not working properly - nightwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394594/loop-is-not-working-properly-nightwatch)

Comment: Not a xPath Error. Its not working with 'waitForElementVisible('body', 20000)' also. As body presents in every DOM. 
        Did I miss anything in switchWindow method?

Comment: The Xpath make your code is hard to read, for example ,can you change ".//*[@id='01r36000000RX00_Tab']/a" to something like "#Tab", or "div[name=tab]'. It is not easy for me(may be for anyone else) to know what do the elements in your test mean.