# Loop is not working properly - nightwatch

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I have this code, I want to go thru all the links available at the bottom of the page. After clicking them I want to make sure the URL opened is the correct one.
I think the the recursive calls are done too early. Another issue is how can I do to tell that link belongs to certain URL.

```
function links(browser, total_links) {
    if (total_links <= 0) {
        browser.end();
        return;
    }

    console.log("Number of links: " + total_links);
    console.log('Flag1');

         browser
            .waitForElementVisible('.bottom .socal>span:nth-child(' + total_links + ')', 1000, function () {

            console.log('Flag2');
            browser.execute('scrollIntoView(alignToBottom)')

            .moveToElement('.bottom .socal>span:nth-child(' + total_links + ')', 3, 3)
                .pause(3000)
                .click('.bottom .socal>span:nth-child(' + total_links + ') a', function () {
                    console.log('Flag3');
                    browser.keys(['\uE006'])
                    //  .assert.urlContains('facebook')
                    //.assert.urlEquals('https://www.facebook.com/unitel.ao/?fref=ts')
                            .window_handles(function (result) {
                            console.log('Flag4');
                            browser.assert.equal(result.value.length, 2, 'There should be two windows open.');
                            var handle_1 = result.value[0];
                            var handle_2 = result.value[1];
                            browser.switchWindow(handle_2, function () {
                                browser.closeWindow()
                                    .switchWindow(handle_1, function () {
                                        total_links = total_links - 1;
                                        links(browser, total_links);
                                    });
                            });
                         });

                    console.log('Flag5');
                });
            console.log('Flag6');   
        });
}

module.exports = {
    'Social links': function (browser) {
        var total_links;

        browser
            .url('http://m.unitel.ao/fit/')
            .execute(function () {
                    return document.querySelectorAll("ul.navbar-nav>li").length;
                },
                function (tags) {
                    total_links = tags.value;
                    links(browser, total_links);

                });

        //  .end();
    }
};
```

Comment: sorry to say too much code and no relevance in the question clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humh, it seems like you were stuck with this days ago.I recommend page-object,it will help you stay away hardcode and easier to change css in the future.

A home page object(home.js) may be like this :

```
module.exports = {
  url: function() {
    return 'http://m.unitel.ao/fit/';
  },
  commands: [{
    getUrl: function(n) {
      if (n === 3) {
        return 'youtube.com/user/tvUNITEL';
      }
      if (n === 1) {
        return 'facebook.com/unitel.ao/?fref=ts';
      }
      if (n === 2) {
        return 'instagram.com/unitelangola/';
      }
      if (n === 4) {
        return 'plus.google.com/110849312028181626033/posts';
      }
    }
  }],
  elements: {
    facebook: {
      selector: '.bottom .socal>span:nth-child(1)',
    },
    instagram: {
      selector: '.bottom .socal>span:nth-child(2)'
    },
    youtube: {
      selector: '.bottom .socal>span:nth-child(3)'
    },
    googleplus: {
      selector: '.bottom .socal>span:nth-child(4)'
    }
  }
};
```

And in your test should be like :

```
module.exports = {
  'Social links': function(browser) {
    const homePage = browser.page.home();
    var j = 0;
    for (var i in homePage.elements) {
      homePage
        .navigate()
        .waitForElementVisible(homePage.elements[i].selector, 5000, false,
          function() {
            browser.pause(3000);
          })
        .click(homePage.elements[i].selector, function() {
          browser
            .pause(2000)
            .window_handles(function(result) {
              url = homePage.getUrl(j + 1);
              var home = result.value[0];
              var handle = result.value[1];
              browser
                .switchWindow(handle)
                .verify.urlContains(url)
                .closeWindow()
                .switchWindow(home);
              j += 1;
            });
        })
    }
  }
};
```

PS:In case you dont know how to create a page-object, here is the doc http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-page-objects.

In config file
[Nightwatch.js](http://%09%20nightwatchjs.org/guide#settings-file):

```
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "./lib/pages", /* you need to add the path,e.g: './lib/pages', */
  "globals_path" : "",
```

Comment: You are right, I´ve been sucked with this for a few days now...Thank you for your help. I have a doubt, the page-object doesn´t run with selenium webdriver? Got this error: "Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server"

Comment: It worked thanks!!! Can I create a page object for dynamic links? What I mean is when I don´t know how many links to click and which ones to click, is there a way to do it? thank you again for your help

Comment: Dynamic links ? can you give an example,there are 4 already,you can have more if you want .
ps:if it worked, please accept answer.

Comment: Accepted! For instance on the page object, imagine that I don´t know that the first one is facebook, it´s a new one, is there a way to know which one  it is and check its URL?

Comment: You should know it, we are doing the test case following the document,the element 'must' be there .If dev team add more link, they should inform you then you write test case and make auto-test for it,that is process.Dont assume the result for  any test case,you must know/expect what is the result.

Comment: could you please give me a hand with dropdown menus? Thanks is advance

Comment: I have 3 choices in the dropdown.It passes the 1st and third ones, it can´t verify the 2nd.       Testing if the URL contains "oyun.azercell.com/homepage?lang=ru".  - expected "oyun.azercell.com/homepage?lang=ru" but got:http://oyun.azercell.com/?lang=az  what can be causing this @Bao Tran?

Comment: oyun.azercell is the one of social (facebook,youtube,..) ,is not it? if it is not related to this topic, make another one for it.

Comment: Could you please have a look on this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523672/click-is-skipping-a-child-element-on-a-dropdown-menu