# Click is skipping a child element on a dropdown menu

Tags: nightwatch.js

Only the first child is ok, second is never clicked, the 3rd option is clicked but changed into the first option too quick that it doesn´t have time to get the URL. Tried to increase pauses and waiting times but it didn´t work.

```
module.exports =  {
'Language Selection': function(browser) {
    const homePage = browser.page.language();
    var j = 0;
    for (var i in homePage.elements) {
        homePage
            .navigate()
            .waitForElementVisible('#azercell_language_selector', 2000)
            .click('#azercell_language_selector');
        //browser
           // .keys(['uE015','uE006']);

                //function(){
            //.pause(1000);
                homePage
                    .waitForElementVisible(homePage.elements[i].selector, 5000,
                        function () {
                            browser.pause(1000);
                            browser.moveToElement(homePage.elements[i].selector, 1,1,
                       function(){
                            browser.pause(5000)
                       })
                        .click(homePage.elements[i].selector,
                        function () {
                        browser
                            .pause(1000)
                            .windowHandles(function (result) {
                                url = homePage.getUrl(j + 1);
                                var home = result.value[0];

                                var handle = result.value[1];
                                browser
                                    .switchWindow(handle)
                                    .pause(5000)
                                    .verify.urlContains(url)
                                    .switchWindow(home);
                                j += 1;
                         //  })
                            })
                    });
          })
    }
}
```

};
Page Object:

```
module.exports = {
    url: function() {
        return 'http://oyun.azercell.com/?lang=az';
    },
    commands: [{
        getUrl: function(n) {
            if (n === 1) {
                return 'oyun.azercell.com/?lang=az';
            }
            if (n === 2) {
                return 'oyun.azercell.com/?lang=ru';
            }
            if (n === 3) {
                return 'oyun.azercell.com/?lang=en';
            }

        }

    }],
    elements: {

        AZ: {
            selector: '#azercell_language_selector>option:nth-child(1)'
        },
        RU: {
            selector:'#azercell_language_selector>option:nth-child(2)'
        },
        EN: {
            selector: '#azercell_language_selector>option:nth-child(3)'
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using Microsoft Edge as the browser, or is it happening in other browsers?

Comment: I´m using firefox, made some changes but still not clicking on the 2nd option, don´t know what´s causing this

Comment: ':nth-child' never works for me in Nightwatch. That would be my first point of investigation.

Comment: @QualiT, Hi there, so what you´re using to replace ':nth-child'?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @BaoTran, Hi Bao, yes I already solved this. Can I ask you if there is any function to count the number of childs? I used "for (i=2;i<('.menuElementsAgregator>li').length; i++)" but the test is endless, I had to force it to stop

Comment: Sorry, if I seemed cryptic. I double checked, and I am using :nth-of-type().  I'll also use xpath and index in. I've not been very helpful here.

Comment: browser.elements function, it will return all of element with same selector in json.

Comment: thank you both. Solved this with ".browser.execute(function)"

Comment: @QualiT, which of the :nth-of-type(), xpath and index in, is more reliable. The :nth-child has so far worked fine for me but I only recently started using  nightwatch.